# Two thebibliography sections in one file; how can I make the labels of the citations different?

Tags: bibliographies

I have two different thebibliography blocks in my file (I can't use bibtex). I want the first one to be numbered differently to the second one. At the moment, both run from 1-10 so cross referencing is not possible. Instead I'd like either bib A goes from 1-10 and bib B goes from 11-20, or something like bib A goes from A1 to A10 and bib B goes from B1 to B10.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}


\begin{document}
\section{First part}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{paper}
A.Author
\newblock Blah
\newblock{ \em B.}, 2016(1), 2016.
\end{thebibliography}

\subsubsection{Second part} 
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibitem{paper2}
B.Author
\newblock {ADSD}.
\newblock {\em ArXiv e-prints}, March 2017.
\end{thebibliography}

Here I cite \cite{paper} and \cite{paper2}

\end{document}
```

If you run it, you'll see both citations are [1].

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable code you have so far ...

Answer (score 2):

We can define a `theprefixbibliography` environment based on `thebibliography` that allows you to specify a prefix.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theprefixbibliography}[2]
  {\begin{thebibliography}{#2}
   \def\@biblabel##1{[#1-##1]}%
   \def\@bibitem##1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
     {\string\bibcite{##1}{#1-\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}}
  {\end{thebibliography}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First part}
\begin{theprefixbibliography}{A}{10}
\bibitem{paper}
A.~Author
\newblock Blah
\newblock{ \em B.}, 2016(1), 2016.
\bibitem{paper4}
A.~Cuthor
\newblock Blah
\newblock{ \em C.}, 2017(1), 2017.
\end{theprefixbibliography}

\subsubsection{Second part} 
\begin{theprefixbibliography}{B}{10}
\bibitem{paper2}
B.~Author
\newblock {ADSD}.
\newblock {\em ArXiv e-prints}, March 2017.
\bibitem{paper3}
B.~Buthor
\newblock {ABCD}.
\newblock {\em ArXiv e-prints}, March 2018.
\end{theprefixbibliography}

Here I cite \cite{paper} and \cite{paper2}

\end{document}
```

[image]